# Change Font Size for Auto-Complete Suggestions Java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, eclipse-kepler

I am using Eclipse Kepler for Java development. 
I successfully managed to increase the font size for the normal editor, however the auto-complete suggestions that it gives you (in that little pop-up menu that appears next to your cursor) are still the same size (as I am using a 4K monitor, the size of those suggestions by default is a bit too small for me to see).

How can I change the font size for those auto-complete suggestions?

Comment: Some basic googling suggests it cannot be done, or that Eclipse uses the System font.

Comment: It seems a bit odd - you can change the font size of the javadoc popups in Window - Preferences - General - Appearance - Colors and Fonts - Java. But I can't spot the one you are after anywhere

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about the content assist. You can browse it from Preferences>Java>Editor>Content Assist

Well, I don't think you can actually do that as there's no option to increase the font size.